# Why am I unable to see AA sample when selected branch path tracing and unable to render animation when select GPU Compute on Mac?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I reinstalled Blender and I'm still unable to see AA sample when I selected Branch Path Tracing.

[image]

Also, when I tried rendering it with GPU Compute, it comes out blank. I really need to figure out how to get the AA samples as I tried to render the animation on CPU 5000 render samples and looks the same (Which is blurry).I also tried rendering this animation on my Windows laptop and it took 7 hours to just render a 2 seconds animation which looks blurry.

Here's the link to my Blender file: [image]

[image]

Comment: are you using an official build and recent version of blender? Is rendering with the default path tracer causing you issues that you had to you the branched path tracer?

Comment: about the GPU error,this could be caused when a scene is too complex to render with your graphic card.to test see how much ram it takes for one frame to render on CPU and see if that value fits in your GPU' VRAM.

Comment: I downloaded the newest version of Blender today so surely is the most recent. No, Path tracing is not causing any issues, I deliberately selected branched path tracking so I could reduce the blurriness. For my windows laptop, it is taking unbelievable long 7 hours for 8 frames that it is so blurry is totally crazy. For other youtube videos i seen it only took them no more than half an hour to render. I also increased the sample render to 800 which was recommended by many people to reduce the blurriness, i guess that did not help. Please help, this is my school assignment and it is due soon.

Comment: My windows laptop have: NVIDIA GT 520M , 8GB of ram , 64-bit operating system.

Comment: I'm afraid i don't have a solution, you could perhaps separate the objects into multiple render layers and [composite](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7573/how-do-i-composite-render-layers-in-2-69-using-cycles) them later on. this may allow you to render with the GPU and not fail. you could also speed up the rendering by only [calculating](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23358/speed-up-cycles-render-only-calculate-whats-visible-to-the-camera) what the camera sees . sadly those are minor speed ups and probably are not worth the trouble. hopefully someone else can help you.

Comment: Would you mind if i can have you email so i could talk to you further about this problem?

Comment: I have a solution to the bluriness. I don't have all the images though (cobblestone and others don't show up), but I have been able to get Steve to be much clearer.

Comment: Can you please tell me the solution? I'm begging for help now as this whole animation weighs 98% of my grade.

Comment: Typing it up now.

Comment: Just sent it. Please do consider my offer at the bottom. You can _Automatically Pack Into .blend_ all image files via the _File > External Data > Automatically Pack Into .blend_ option.

Comment: Please do not ask more than one question per post.

Comment: Ok, I'm so sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot help with your GPU because I don't have access to your computer. However, I was able to figure out the bluriness.

### Problem

In your scene, one of the first things I noticed was that it was inside an enclosed space. Bluriness in enclosed spaces can often be caused by low lighting.

### Solution

I selected the area lamp near the top of the cabin and turned up the *Emission Strength* to 1000 from 300. I also turned the *Max Bounces:* to 1024.

#### I also optimized the .blend file.

I made some adjustments in the *Render tab* of the *Properties panel*, namely that I set the *Max:* and *Min:* Light Path Bounces to 0 (for faster rendering). I also turned the *Filter Glossy:* value to 0.7. Additionally, I changed the resolution to just 1920x1080 (1080p; you had it set to 4k which really won't make any difference except causing the rendering to take 4 times as long). Furthermore, I turned the *Sampling > Settings: > Clamp Indirect:* value to 3.00. I turned the AA render samples to 100. Lastly, I optimized the Tile Size for CPU rendering (*Properties panel > Render Tab > Performance Drop Down Menu > Tiles:*). If you want it to be optimized for GPU rendering, change each (x/y) from *16* to *256*.

On my 8-year-old mac with CPU and not all the image textures, one frame (probably) took a bit under an hour (I didn't wait for it to finish). On my Nvidia 970 4GB STRIX, one frame took just 54 seconds and looked like this:

[image]

### Final Notes

Here is the fixed up .blend file:

[image]

*I don't generally offer this (haven't before), but if you can get me a .blend file with all the images included, I will render it for you. 90 frames x 1 min each = about 90 min. --A fellow Blender-using student.*

Comment: The images were basically from this website: https://github.com/TheDuckCow/MCprep/releases once you download it comes as an addon for blender. You import the addon and select an object in the secene click mcprep mineways and prep materials and everything should be in coloured.

Comment: Can you not do what I suggested in the comments? I may be able to follow the link, but I'm pressed for time today.

Comment: Oh yes, I want to thank you so much for helping me!. I was wondering whether I could have your email or something so I keep in touch with you.

Comment: I'll always answer on the stack exchange app, but there is a thing called chat on BSE. Maybe I'll look into that. P.s. If my answer helped, please consider accepting it (the check mark) and the one on your other question. I will try to follow that link later today to render.

Comment: Ok! I want to thank you again for all your help!

Comment: You're very welcome.

Comment: I'll contact you soon from the chat in BSE. P.S I think ill just need you to find me the best render settings like what you have done today. I'll render the whole animation by myself as because if we keep sharing files it would take forever to download and upload.

Comment: Ok. I added a chat called ShadyPuck. You can contact me there. Don't forget to accept, please! Also, that link is for Windows, and I have a mac.

Comment: Hi, I downloaded the file you uploaded. I was wondering whether it is possible to reduce the light indoor so it doesn't look like it is day time?

Comment: Possibly. But it might be more blurry.

Comment: Hi, Shady Puck I'm closing into finishing my animation. I'm wondering whether you could render it for me?

Comment: @JeffTeoh If you can get me a .blend with all of the images, caches, and whatever else, then sure (you could share a google drive link).

Comment: How would i be able to include all the images into a blender file? Can I just send you my whole folder with all the images?

Comment: @JeffTeoh That would be fine.

Comment: I just figured how to pack all the textures into a file. So now I'm uploading  the Blender file. Can I give it to you tomorrow?

Comment: @JeffTeoh Just let me know when and where.

Comment: Would you be able to render it as png? Because I still need to import all of them into Adobe Premie Pro.

Comment: @JeffTeoh A sequence of PNGs could take up several GB. I could do it, but it would be very unwieldy.

Comment: I'm so sorry for the inconvenience :-(.

Comment: I'll give you the blend file around this week. I'm wondering whether you have an email address I could contact you with?

Comment: @JeffTeoh Can you not post the link in chat and let me know, or even just comment it?

Comment: Well, I tried joining your chat but got no response. If you want I can just post the link here and we can communicate on here.

Comment: @JeffTeoh That would be best. I didn't get any notifications from the chat, but I'll accept you later.

Comment: This is the link:  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6r1cIO-s6iGWU5Tek5rTnM1NUU

Comment: If it doesn't work I'll try again. Thanks alot for helping !

Comment: Your welcome. I should be able to start it around 4 when I get home.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40791/discussion-between-shady-puck-and-jeff-teoh).